# How to generate a "value-frequency" table with random numbers?

Tags: list-manipulation, latex

I want to create a "value-frequency" table from the following expression.

```
Counts[Sort[RandomInteger[{1, 5}, 500]]] // TableForm
```

The generated table should be in LaTeX form either

- two rows and n columns. first row: Value, second row: Frequency
- n rows and 2 columns. first column: Value, second column: Frequency

Optionally with headings "Value" and "Frequency" to make it look nice.

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SeedRandom[1]
counts = Counts[Sort[RandomInteger[{1, 5}, 500]]];
TeXForm @ Grid[Join[{{"Value", "Frequency"}}, KeyValueMap[List][counts]], Dividers -> All]
```

> $\begin{array}{|c|c|}
> \hline
>  \text{Value} & \text{Frequency} \\
> \hline
>  1 & 104 \\
> \hline
>  2 & 92 \\
> \hline
>  3 & 97 \\
> \hline
>  4 & 101 \\
> \hline
>  5 & 106 \\
> \hline
> \end{array}$

```
TeXForm@Grid[Transpose@Join[{{"Value", "Frequency"}}, KeyValueMap[List][counts]],
   Dividers -> All]
```

> $\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
> \hline
>  \text{Value} & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
> \hline
>  \text{Frequency} & 104 & 92 & 97 & 101 & 106 \\
> \hline
> \end{array}$

Answer (score 4):

One way to make your table:

```
TeXForm@TableForm[Sort[Tally@RandomInteger[{1, 5}, 500]], 
        TableHeadings -> {None, {"Value", "Frequency"}}]
```

The output is the Latex code for:

$\begin{array}{cc}
 \text{Value} & \text{Frequency} \\
 1 & 89 \\
 2 & 94 \\
 3 & 117 \\
 4 & 93 \\
 5 & 107 \\
\end{array}$